# GIMP doesn't open

Tags: macports

I installed gimp from macports on my MacBook Air Mavericks. When I launch GIMP 2.8 from launchpad it pops up in dock for a second and vanishes.
system log shows

```
26/05/14 8:43:28.086 pm com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[149]: (org.gimp.GIMP.56000[372]) Exited with code: 1
```

and also I did

```
$ /Applications/MacPorts/GIMP.app/Contents/MacOS/GIMP 

(GIMP:1219): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
    Using the fallback 'C' locale.
Cannot open display:
```

Comment: Since GIMP 2.8.2 it's been available as a native app for OS X. No need to install it via MacPORTS, no need for an X11 server to be running to use it. My suggestion is you ditch the MacPORTs version and get it directly from here: http://www.gimp.org/downloads/ -- you'll save yourself a ton of dependency headaches. It'll Just Work(tm).

Comment: The warning means that you haven't got an X11 server started, or that you haven't set the right environment for it if it is started. To solve that, install XQuartz - start it and from the a xterm window that appears, run the GIMP program using the command in your question. OTOH I would still just recommend using the native build.

Comment: Yeah i'm good with native build. I've gone for macports coz i'm an ubuntu user;  u know the apt-get n all... ThankU

Comment: Well then, I'll post that as an answer. ;)

Comment: U serious? U gotto do tht?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The MacPORTs version of GIMP isn't really well maintained. It *should* be doing a native build but from your error log it looks like it's doing an X11 build. Having to run an X11 server to use GIMP would be...silly, right?

Since GIMP 2.8.2 it's been available as a native app for OS X. No need to install it via MacPORTS, no need for an X11 server to be running to use it. My suggestion is you ditch the MacPORTs version and get it directly from here: http://gimp.org/downloads -- you'll save yourself a ton of dependency headaches. It'll Just Work(tm).

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific reason to suspect a permission from what you have described.

Could you elaborate on what exactly you have installed, from where you got it, and how you installed it?

If you download the pre-compiled binary from gimp.org for OS X (Native Build) and get version 2.8.2 or later (preferably get the newest version 2.8.10) - the installation package should be self-contained.

If you have installed an earlier version, you need to install an X11 environment first. If this is a new Mavericks installed, you need to download and install XQuartz before it will run. Note: This is only if you install an old version of GIMP - I would recommend simply installing the latest version.

If you have already installed the latest version of the native build of GIMP from gimp.org, then try this approach to finding the reason for the program not starting:

1. Open Terminal.app
2. Run command: open /Applications/GIMP.app

(or whatever the application is called on your system)

Check the terminal window for error messages that could indicate the reason for the program not starting up correctly.

Comment: I said I installed from macports i.e. `sudo port install gimp`. OSX 10.9.2

Comment: Don't do that. Use the native build which will cause you the least problems. If you insist on using macports, take my advice on installing an X11 environment.